# How to force preview to open window in current desktop

Tags: mojave, pdf, preview, desktop

I am facing a super stupid problem which is completely killing my productivity.

I have my laptop attached to an external monitor. Desktop 1 is on the laptop and desktop 2 is on the external screen. 
From desktop 2, I open a PDF file with preview.

Instead of opening it inside desktop 2, it automatically switches whatever is full screen on my laptop monitor and opens the PDF on desktop 1.

This is driving me mad. Why isn't the default behavior the obvious one? (namely open the window exactly where the open command comes from)

Is there anything I can do to make it behave in the logical way?

Thanks!

ps: MacOs 10.14.4 Mojave

edit: adding picture regarding comment
[image]

Comment: 1) Is Preview already running when you do this? 2) Right click Preview's icon in the Dock & tell us what is selected in Options>Assign to...

Comment: @Tetsujin The behavior is the same wheter preview is already open or not. Weird I don't have 'assign to' in the options list in the dock ( I have 'keep in dock', 'open at login', 'show in finder', none checked)

Comment: All apps have an assign to [desktop]; I've never seen one without.

Comment: Have you set your external monitor as primary screen on system preferences? I can't see the "assign to" option either.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have edited the post to show a screenshot

Comment: I would imagine you only get 'assign to' once you have more than one Space defined. [Not something I'm going to test, I have 7 sets of Spaces, very carefully assigned.] If you only actually have one defined Space & you do everything else in fullscreen, then you're not taking advantage of Spaces properly.

Comment: @Tetsujin by 'space' you mean desktop? If yes, I said it in the post, there are 2 desktops, desktop 1 is on the laptop, desktop 2 is on the external screen

Comment: @LvcasX1 my primary screen is the laptop one (the menu bar is there in the settings)

Comment: Ok, I've tried with two options: setting your external monitor screen as primary and the second was with this "assign to" option, this options will appear if you have more than one desktop in both displays so you will have to create them and then open preview and you will see this option in the "option" item in the list.

Comment: @LvcasX1 thanks for the tip! now I can see the option. However that's not really answering the question, I would like preview to just open where I am working, not in a fixed place. If for instance I was working on the laptop monitor I would want it to open there

Comment: @ClonedOne I was trying to assign it just to the active display but if you select "all desktops" or "none" options it will just display on primary display. If you select assign it to an specific desktop it will work. (never seen it before so I'm just learning how it works)

Comment: @LvcasX1 thanks for helping with this :) I hope someone will know the answer, this bug is destroying my focus

Comment: I think your title should say "... in current desktop when on second monitor".  Because on the primary monitor it does open in the current desktop.  But I agree, it's super frustrating, I have had the exact same issue and it seems this is a bug in Previews behavior.  It's truly annoying.  I open PDFs in Skim by default unless I need to modify the PDF (Skim uses the underlying PDF viewer of the OS, so the experience is similar to Preview and it has much better annotating features – but it can't do stuff like add or delete pages etc.)